# PgAudit on AlmaLinux9

Tags: postgresql, pgaudit

I'm trying to install PgAudit on a virtual machine with Alma Linux 9, i already installed postgresql 15.2, i followed the steps provided at github but at the last step, when i try to execute this:
[root@localhost pgaudit]# make install USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config

This happens
Makefile:16: /usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: * No rule to make target '/usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.

I've read that this problem might be solved on Debian/Ubuntu by installing the server development packages, but i haven't found a solution to solve this problem on Almalinux 9. Thanks for your help